# deploying php with capistrano v3

Tags: php, capistrano, continuous-deployment, capistrano3

I've set up Capistrano v3 for deploying (I'm pretty new to capistrano). It works fine and after `cap production deploy` my code is pulled from github to my server in the `/var/www/my_app/releases/{release_number}` path.
The server code is running under /var/www/my_app. 
I assumed that Capistrano should deploy the code from `/var/www/my_app/releases/{release_number}` to `/var/www/my_app/`, but that's not the case.

Do I have to move my code by myself or am I missing anything in my config?

Here is my config (deploy.rb):

```
set :application, 'oratio'

set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'path/to/github'

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app"

set :pty, true

set :format, :pretty

namespace :deploy do
    #do nothing
end
```